# Where is the dynamic memory associated with std::bind?

Tags: c++, c++11

The problem is that since you can use std:bind in a loop with an arbitrary number of iterations, the storage cannot be inline.  It doesn't appear to be on the heap, since it doesn't appear to generate memory leaks.  It seems, then, that it must be on the stack - SOME stack.  I have an application which could easily do hundreds of thousands of these binds setting up calls to a threader.  Since the caller could presumably go out of scope while the threader is still working, and since the threader needs the bind until it executes the job, that information must be stored SOMEWHERE.  Where is it, and how do I clean it up when the binds have served their purpose?

Example:

```
std::function<void()> *Jobs;  
Jobs = new std::function<void()> Jobs[nJobs];  
for (i=0; i<nJobs; ++i)  
{  
    Jobs[i] = std::bind (funtion, args, ...);  
}  
ThreadPool->QueueJobs (Jobs, nJobs); // store POINTERS to jobs  
ThreadPool->WaitForCompletion();  
delete Jobs;
```

Does this look like it will work?

Comment: where do you store the objects returned by std::bind?

Comment: Winston:
That's the point. If the std:bin is an argument to a function, where does it get stored? In the past, I have done threading by calling void functions with single arguments. Those arguments were pointers to structs, and I managed the memory associated with those structs myself. But while that *concept* holds across multiple platforms, the code required to do it does not. C++11 offers a cross-platform way of doing it, but I can't understand how it works. It looks to me like the stuff of which stack-heap collisions are made.

Comment: `Does this look like it will work?` - try it. See if it does. If it does, ask on Code Review.SE to review it (they will want the full application - not prototype code).  If it doesn't, work out a good question and ask it on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since `Jobs` is an array, you should `delete[]` not `delete`. I think you get away with sorting pointers in QueueJobs because you WaitForCompletition before deleting it. But I would suggest having QueueJobs take a copy, to avoid the possibility of the pointers being deleted. A better solution would be to replace your array with std::vector which will manage the memory for you.

Comment: Sorry about the delete. The idea behind "POINTERS" is that QueueJobs doesn't need to make copies, and the idea behind "WaitForCompletion" is that when the main thread returns from it, the threader has finished all the Jobs and has no further use for the std::binds, at which point Jobs can be deleted.  But in any case, you've answered my question. Thank you, Winston.

Answer (score 5):

The return value of std::bind is entirely on the stack. If you just called std::bind and did nothing else with it it would be on the stack and then disappear when it went out of scope.

In order to do anything useful with the result of std::bind you must have explicitly or implicitly made a copy of it, probably to some place in the heap.

For example, if you did this:

```
std::function foo(std::bind(this, "yellow"));
```

The `std::function` will copy the result of `std::bind` to the heap. When the `std::function` is destroyed it will automatically release the memory for the copy.

If you did something like:

```
vector_of_function.push_back(std::function(std::bind(this, "yellow")));
```

The `std::bind` will be copied into heap allocated by the `std::function` and the `std::function` will be copied into heap allocated by the `std::vector`. But in neither case do you need to worry about it because the vector and function will take care of deallocation when they are destroyed.

The rule in C++ is that whatever you `new` you must `delete`. Since the standard library is responsible for `new` the copies in these cases, the standard library will `delete` them.

Comment: Now that makes sense.  I'll revise my original post with an example.  Please comment on it.

Comment: Your answer is technically incorrect, as it ignores return value  optimization, meaning that the value returned by bind is likely to be placed immediately in its destination, which in the example given is on the heap not the stack. However, this makes no practical difference, so your answer is correct in spirit.

Comment: @Jules, yes, you are technically correct: the best kind of correct. I thought that discussing that would be too confusing.

Comment: maybe you can mention type erasure